# Firebase function is letting Invalid emails to be allowed

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am new to Firebase, sorry if this seems basic

I wrote a segment of code that should register a user. And it does just that, but, I can fill in an email that does not exist.

*This is not the full code, just the function that is responsible for this*

```
window.createUser = function (email, password) {
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function () {
    location.reload();
}).catch(function (error) {
    if (document.getElementById("lemail").value == "" && document.getElementById("lpassword").value == "") {
        $("#lalert").html("<strong>Oh no! </strong> Looks like the email or password inputs are not filled out!");
        $("#lalert").show();

    } else {

        $("#lalert").html("<strong>Oh no! </strong>" + aTranslate(error.code));
        $("#lalert").show();
    }
  });  
}
```

`aTranslate()` is a function that gets the error code and changes it into a customized message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If an email that doesn't exist is an email that is not real and made up, then Firebase authentication does not check to see whether or not an email is legit or a made up one. You would have to test whether it is a valid email or not by yourself.

Comment: You don't have to test the email yourself. The Firebase API includes the [`emailVerified`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#emailVerified) property and the [sendEmailVerification](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#sendEmailVerification) function for managing this. So you don't have to do it *entirely* by yourself.

Comment: I'd consider that a separate (and more complete) answer @cartant. :-)

Comment: how would I check for whether the email is legit?

Comment: other than using the email verification

Answer (score 0):

I recently been working on the same thing. To get by this you have to work with the errorCodes and error messages. You should have something like this to check if the firebase user exist. Checking for each of the error codes avoid fake accounts or user that you have disable from using your application.

```
            var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
        if (errorCode === 'auth/wrong-password' || errorCode === 'auth/invalid-email' || errorCode === 'auth/user-disabled' || errorCode === 'auth/user-not-found') {
            window.alert(errorMessage);
        }
```

This is completely in JS thou if you would like you can change it to JQuery. Hope this helps!